# Why in a block device a read or write request is sent more than once

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am having this problem that I can not explain: I wrote a block device driver for a network attached hard drive. And what I see in the logs is that read and write requests are sent to the block more than once each. In some cases, I see the same request sent five times.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. insmod the block device driver.
2. run the command:

   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rb bs=8196

**my device is /dev/rb.

My assumption is that I should only two write requests going to the block device; one for each block and I am writing two blocks.

Comment: it may depends on your implementation of read and write. We can see?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://bitbucket.org/hebbo_pub/networkblockdevice/src/56fa20ebbb5eb4ae06f29e00ca8477219aad288a/DiskOnRAM/ram_block.c?at=master) is the code. Beware, it is experimental and for learning purposes.

Comment: and can you also attach a log?